# VirtualBox 5.1 Not Starting on Kali Linux 2016.2

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox

I tried installing VirtualBox 5.1 on Kali Linux 2016.2. I did this by running

```
                         apt-get install virtualbox
```

(I'm logged in as root, so no need for sudo). This worked fine, a few errors during the install, but the resulting app worked. I launched it, made a VM, and once I tried to run said VM, it told me it was missing a critical kernel driver (vboxdrv), and that I should run

```
                             modprobe vboxdrv
```

I did this, and the result was

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/4.6.0-kali1-amd64
```

I tried running

```
dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms
apt-get --reinstall install virtualbox-dkms
service vboxdrv setup
apt-get install linux-headers-amd64
/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

(Not in that order)

I also tried

```
dpkg -i virtualbox-5.1_5.1.14-112924~Debian~wheezy_amd64.deb
```

with the Debian Wheezy .deb file on the VirtualBox site, but that one didn't even start up.

None of these worked. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Did you by any chance manually upgrade the kernel?

Answer (score 5):

Upgrade your kernel version :

Run : `apt-cache search linux-image` then install the latest version. e,g:

```
apt-get install linux-image-4.8.0-kali2-amd64
```

Install the `linux-headers` :

```
apt-get install linux-headers-4.8.0-kali2-amd64
```

Reboot your system

remove `virtualbox` , then reinstall it as follows:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install dkms
apt-get install virtualbox virtualbox-dkms 
modprobe vboxdrv
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the virtualbox package, you need to install the virtualbox-dkms and virtualbox-qt (for GUI front end) packages...  at least this is how it works on Mint and Ubuntu, which Kali is based on... Also Mint has an issue with the menu shortcut not showing up until you log off and log back in...

For your missing module issue, the virtualbox-dkms package is the critical one...